# How to get PHP to store requested URLs in error_log file?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting a bunch of errors on Production environment that I can't reproduce locally. Therefore I'm looking to find out which URL the user is requesting. This URL is currently not being outputted to the error log, so I'm just wondering how I would go by displaying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print to log file using `trigger_error` (http://php.net/trigger_error), ie:

```
trigger_error($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
```

`trigger_error` by default generates user level notification, so it will not break anything.

if `REQUEST_URI` is not enough, please check [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php).

Comment: How does this answer the OP? He wants the Request_URL to be printed in the php error-log file when an error happens in his code. So he can trace where that error might come from. trigger_error only writes to the log.